# Cookies does not seem to be set properly

Tags: java, android, http, cookies

I manage to log in and get cookies with respect to the session. But when I try to make a new request the login-information seems to be lost (the HTML-data is the same for both the requests. The second request should provide my username plus some other data).

I set the cookie like this before I send a new request (the DefaultHttpClient instance is the same):

```
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

    if(cookies != null)
    {
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
        {
            String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain();  
            httppost.addHeader("Cookie",cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + ";");
            System.out.println(cookieString);
        }
    }  

    try
    {
        //System.out.println(httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies());
        response = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost,localContext);
    }
```

I have checked the cookie information, and it seems that it returns two different "cookie-instances" (two session ID`s) which I set in the for-loop above. But still it doesn't seem to work.
What can be the problem?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create a static instance of cookie store globally 

     cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

 // Create local HTTP context

    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

// Bind custom cookie store to the local context
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
//execute your connection with context
  HttpResponse response = http.execute(post,localContext);


And then whenever you connect use that static cookie instance to connect
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
// Bind custom cookie store to the local context
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, StaticInstance(cookieStore));
//and as usual
response = http.execute(post,localContext);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess http in http.execute(...) is a DefaultHttpClient instance? And it should therefor manage cookies automatically so I don`t have to set them myself?

Comment: Will give you feedback as soon as I have tried your solution :)

Comment: Turns out it worked all the time. The mistake I did was that I try to print out the server respons as a string. But the string is to big for the console window (so it didn`t print out all the data). Thanks for your help though, and your solution works as well so the answer is accepted :)